# Why doesn't a command that works inside a docker container work from outside via docker run?

Tags: linux, npm, docker, circleci, linux-containers

I have a container called `my_container` when I run `docker run -i -t my_container` I can then run `npm --version` and I get `2.7.4`.

However when I try to run the same command from outside the container using `docker run --workdir=/home/ubuntu/www my_container npm --version` I get an error message:

> Unable to locate npm.
>   lxc-start: The container failed to start.
>   lxcstart: Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.

Most commands I run have this same behavior not just `npm`. I am doing this in Circle CI if that adds any more clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the container's `entrypoint` is designed to give you a shell, but not take arguments. You can use `docker inspect` to view the entrypoint of the image.

```
$ docker build -
FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM busybox
 ---> 8c2e06607696
Step 1 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
 ---> Running in eb5b4d32af96
 ---> ad1286aebbe2
Removing intermediate container eb5b4d32af96
Successfully built ad1286aebbe2

13:59 ~ $ docker run --rm -ti ad1286aebbe2 echo hi
/bin/sh: can't open 'echo'
```

`busybox` official doesn't have an entrypoint, so arguments get treated as a command, which means they go straight to /bin/sh -c.

Comment: The Dockerfile I'm using doesn't have an entrypoint and echo works fine but npm doesn't

Comment: The Dockerfile may not have an entrypoint, but the image may still have one if the `FROM` statement is of an image that already has an entrypoint.

Comment: When I run docker inspect there are two places "Entrypoint" appears and they are both "null"